# wave function collapse ignores some adjacent tile entropys

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble finding the problem with my wfc program. I don't know where the problem is, but I suspect it is because the options for the tiles are being reset after being spliced. I have tried to fix the problem on my own as well and trying to research the problem but have come up empty. I will only include code i think is most relevent,but my full code can be found [here](https://codehs.com/sandbox/id/wave-function-collapse-oXexrp/embed/?display_mode=default&show_file_tree=False), but I am not sure if it works.

for clarity, wave function collapse in the context of programming is generating random tiles that connect together with a set of rules. it is based on wave function collapse in quantum mechanics. mine specifically generates T-shaped tiles where the end of each tile should always connect to another end of tile. a VERY good explination can be found [here](https://robertheaton.com/2018/12/17/wavefunction-collapse-algorithm/).

currently when I run my program it often looks something like this:
[image: wfcexample]

you'll notice they are not randomly placed. some of them have been placed with at least one direction connected to another. not all of this is random. a correctly running program will be so none of the lines end. if required, [here is the link to the tutorial I used](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rI_y2GAlQFM).
I believe this should be enough information to further explain my problem and what exactly wfc is.

here is how I pick a random tile to collapse. it is messy, but I have not found a more efficient way to do it yet. I hope this is not too much of a problem.

```
function updateGameArea() {
var minEntropy = 1000;
gameArea.clear();
unsortedGrid = [];
sortedGrid = [];
//fill an array with all the values of the grid
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    if (grid[i][j].collapsed == false) {
      unsortedGrid.push(grid[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
//find lowest entropy
for (i = 0; i < unsortedGrid.length; i++) {
  //test if the entropy of the viewed tile is less than minEntropy
  if (unsortedGrid[i].options.length < minEntropy) {
    //if it is, set minEntropy to the tiles entropy
    minEntropy = unsortedGrid[i].options.length;
  }
  //get all the tiles of lowest entropy
  for (i = 0; i < unsortedGrid.length; i++) {
    //if a tiles entropy is == minEntropy, add it to sortedGrid
    if (unsortedGrid[i].options.length == minEntropy) {
      sortedGrid.push(unsortedGrid[i]);
    }
  }
}

//picka random tile
tilePick = Math.floor(Math.random() * sortedGrid.length);
if (gameArea.keys && gameArea.keys[78] && buttonPressed == false) {
  let pickedTile = grid[sortedGrid[tilePick].x][sortedGrid[tilePick].y];
  //set the options of picked tile to a  random option of it
  pickedTile.options = [Math.floor(Math.random() * pickedTile.options.length)];
  buttonPressed = true;
}

if (gameArea.keys && !gameArea.keys[78]) {
  buttonPressed = false;
}
```

this evauluates the entropy of adjacent tiles and removes options that are not valid. this part of code is inside the same function as the one above, namely updateGameArea()

```
let newGrid = []
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  newGrid[i] = [];
  for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    newGrid[i][j] = grid[i][j];
    if (grid[i][j].collapsed == true) {
      newGrid[i][j] = grid[i][j];
    } else {
      let options = [blank, up, down, left, right];
      if (j > 0) {
        let validOptions = [];
        let northTile = grid[i][j - 1];
        for (let option of northTile.options) {
          let valid = connections[option][up];
          validOptions = validOptions.concat(valid);
        }
        checkValid(option, validOptions);
      }

      if (j < size) {
        let validOptions = [];
        let southTile = grid[i][j + 1];
        for (let option of southTile.options) {
          let valid = connections[option][down];
          validOptions = validOptions.concat(valid);
        }
        checkValid(option, validOptions);
      }

      if (i > 0) {
        let validOptions = [];
        let eastTile = grid[i - 1][j];
        for (let option of eastTile.options) {
          let valid = connections[option][left];
          validOptions = validOptions.concat(valid);
        }
        checkValid(option, validOptions);
      }

      if (i < size) {
        let validOptions = [];
        let westTile = grid[i + 1][j];
        for (let option of westTile.options) {
          let valid = connections[option][right];
          validOptions = validOptions.concat(valid);
        }
        checkValid(option, validOptions);
      }

      newGrid[i][j].options = options;
    }
  }
}
//set the grid to the newGrid
grid = newGrid;
}
//End of function
```

this is the function that removes the tiles

```
function checkValid(options,allowed) {
    for(let i =  0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if(allowed.includes(connections[options[i]]) == true) {
            options.splice(0, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

this consists of the majoraty of my code, but not all of it. I hope this is not too much.

Comment: What does "wave function collapse" mean here? I'm only familiar with that term in the context of quantum mechanics.

Comment: The second code snippet has an extra `}` with no matching `{`

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?